# Delaying shutoff of one of 2 output pins using Mlab C on pic16f15275

Tags: c, mplab

I am new to C and any type of programming (2 weeks now with no schooling on the matter), so If I ask a silly question, please bear with me .
I did program a PIC16F15275 with a program.
right now, a momentary switch at RD1 turns on output RD7 and RC7. I would like RC7 the stop a second slower than the other after I release the switch but what I have right now causes both to have a delayed stop.
what do I need to add or change ?
Thanks in advance

```
/**
  Main Source File

  Company: ChieF plow controllers
  plow_controllers@twc.com

  File Name: main.c
  Device            :  PIC16F15275
  Driver Version    :  2.00
*/

/*
*/
int counter = 0;
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

/*
                         Main application
 */
void main(void)
{   
    SYSTEM_Initialize(); // initialize the device

         while ( RC5 == 0 ) //senses POWER LED as OFF    
    {/**B*/ 
         //tap on POWER SWITCH (LOCKING FUNCTION) TURNS ON RC7 pwr LITE AND RA5 backlight PLUS OTHER FUNCTIONS BELOW IT    
        if (RB4 == 0) RC5 = 1, RA5 = 1;
          while  (RA5 == 1) //POWER LED SENSED AS ON and ALLOWS FUNCTIONS IN BRACKETS "C" TO WORK*
            {//C all standard functions 
              //OFF SWITCH RB5. TURNS OFF OTHER FUNCTIONS BELOW IF THEY ARE ON
            { if (RB5 == 0)  RC5 = 0,RA5 = 0, RD1 = 0, RE0 = 0 , RC7 = 0, RC3 = 0, RE2 = 0;}
        
            //(UP) (MOMENTARY) RD1 COIL 5 . RE0 COIL 7
                { if (RB1 == 0) RE0 = 1 , RD1 = 1, RC3 = 0, RC7 = 0; else  RE0 = 0, RD1 = 0;}  
        // NOT WORKING CORRECTLY!! RE0 OUPUT VOLTAGE TOO LOW, OTHER 3 OUTPUTS WORK
            //(DOWN)(LOCKING) RC7 FLOAT LIGHT . RC3  COIL 6 
                { if (RB0 == 0) RC7 = 1 , RC3 = 1 ;}              
            //RIGHT (MOMENTARY) RB3 to RE2 COIL 4  + RE0 COIL 7 //
                { if (RB3 == 0) RE0 = 1 , RE2 = 1; else  RE0 = 0, RE2 = 0;}
         /**NOT WORKING -- RE0 OUTPUT VOLTAGE TOO LOW
               REO VOLTAGE IS BEING AFFECTED BY COMMANDS BELOW THAT ALSO USE THIS OUTPUT ??*/     
        // LEFT (MOMENTARY) RB2 IS SWITCH TO (RE2 COIL 4 +RD1 COIL 5+ RE0 COIL 7*/            
                if(RB2 == 0 && counter <= 2) 
                for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter ++)
                { RE0 = 1; RA6 = 1; __delay_ms(500);}  
                if(RB2 == 1)
                 { counter = 0 , RE0 = 0, RA6 = 0 ;}
         /**THIS DELAY IS ONLY SUPPOSED TO DELAY RA6 FOR 1 SECOND, BUT IT ALSO DELAYS RE0 
          *USING REO HERE DOES NOT ALLOW THE UP AND RIGHT FUNCTIONS REO TO WORK RIGHT
          * IF i REMOVE REO HERE,IT WORKS ON RIGHT BUT STILL NOT ON UP ?? 
          SO !, IT LOOKS LIKE A PRIORITIZATION OR SHARING ISSUE IS IN THE CODE*/
     
          }  /**C*/        
  
    }/**B*/
 

    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
    }
}/*A*/
```

Comment: where is your `main`loop?

Comment: I did not put post the entire program here.

Comment: Hi Mike   I just revised the post to include a more complete program. FYI: it also has another issue with problems using an output in more than one switch function.

Comment: Your code is really hard to read. Try to use `{....}`for every `if` and avoid the comma operator. The `while(1)`loop is empty?